# Delete whole row based on one of clusturing column value in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cql3

Schema I am using is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
id int,
name varchar,
PRIMARY KEY ((id),name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name desc);
```

I wanted to delete records by following command :

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Jhon';
```

But gived error

```
[Invalid query] message="Some partition key parts are missing: name"
```

As I looked for the reason, I came to know that only delete in not possible only with clustering columns.

Then I tried

```
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE name='Jhon') AND name = 'Jhon';
```

But obviously it did not work.

I then tried with setting TTL to 0 for deleting row. But TTL can be set only for particular column, not the entire row.

What are feasible alternates to perform this operation?

Comment: This is not going to be efficient but you could first try to determine `id` by using `allow filtering` and then issuing `delete` with both `id` and `name`.

Comment: Leaving aside efficiency for a second, it's not even working!

Comment: The query suggested by @SergeiZ looks like `SELECT * from mytable where name='John' ALLOW FILTERING ;` That would be inneficient / non scalable etc... Ok to play on your laptop, but not ok in production.

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra, you need to design your data model to support your query. When you query your data, you always have to provide the partition key (otherwise the query would be inefficient).

The problem is that you want to query your data without a partition key. You would need to denormalize your data to support this kind or request. For example, you could add an **additional** table, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE id_by_name(
name varchar,
id int,
name varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (name, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id desc);
```

Then, you would be able to do your delete with a few queries:

1. SELECT ID from id_by_name WHERE name='John';

let's assume this returns 4.

2. DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id=4;
3. DELETE FROM id_by_name WHERE name='John' and id=4;

You could try to leverage materialized view (instead of maintaining yourself id_by_name) but materialized views are currently marked as unstable.

Now, there are still a few issues you need to address in your data model, in particular, how do you handle multiple user with the same name etc...

Comment: I have another query where I need to order records by 'name', will above schema support that?

Comment: You can only set an order within a partition, based on the clustering you choose.

Comment: Yes, so what is way out to support deletion by name and ordering by name at the same time?

Comment: If you have a set of limitid users (thousands), you could create a single partition, with as clustering columns the names. A bit better would be to create multiple partitions (such as the first letter of the names) and put your users in the correct partitions. You could use the 2 first letters to increase the number of partitions, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete primary key if not complete. Primary key decisions are for sharding and load balancing. Cassandra can get complex if you are not used to thinking in columns.

I don't like the above answer, which though is good, complicates your solution. If you are thinking relational but getting lost in Cassandra I suggest using something that simplifies and maps your thinking to relational views.